# OutSystems PWA Azure AD Login

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-graph-api, outsystems

we have an OutSystems Mobile App (PWA)
We would like to add Azure AD SSO

We have tried Idp Mobile, but it is not for PWA

We have tried to embed in an iframe the login to login.microsoftonline.com, but it is not framable (CSP)
So we tried to follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/graph/auth-v2-user
but again the html returned by the authorize api is not framable :(
is there a solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

AAD does not permit framing of pages where credentials are entered as it requires user interaction. When you try Azure Active Directory (AAD) login page inside an iframe, you may go through errors due to defensive measures taken by AAD to prevent malicious attacks.
Some workarounds you may possibly try which may work in few cases.

1. Make sure reply urls set are same everywhere in app and in portal.
2. AAD has headers set to prevent their login page from being displayed in a frame.
   prompt parameter indicates the type of user interaction that is required.Try setting it to none which means user interaction not required(if it is ok in your case).It is optional parameter added in login url in the iframe (&prompt=none).
3. Also &domain_hint={userdomain.com} is added at the end or url request where {userdomain.com} is the last part of the user's email address - e.g.user@userdomain.com >  [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)
4. Try to close and test few times to make sure it works and then login with work account in edge or chrome browser.(or  from https://portal.office.com)

Reference:
[aad-iframe | nafis.dev](https://nafis.dev/2021/03/12/aad-iframe/)